# How to prevent fetching multiple times in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I got this code

```
const UseHttpRequest = async () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  
    await fetch("https://frontend-assignment-api.goodrequest.com/api/v1/shelters")
               .then((shelters) => shelters.json()
               .then((shelters) => dispatch(fetchShelters(shelters.shelters)))
  );
};
```

and i use it in another component called **StepOne** but it keeps fetching infinite times and if I use `useEffect` hook it crashes and says that it is invalid hook call. Can't get it to work

Comment: Where do you try use `useEffect` hook ?

Comment: `it keeps fetching infinite times` you must be doing something wrong elsewhere - this code won't do anything infinitely

Comment: [A complete guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/). Sounds like you're missing the empty array `useEffect(() => { ... }, [])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think hooks can be `async` functions. Also, hook names should start with `use` (not `Use`).

It should work just fine with `useEffect`. For instance, if you want to fetch once when the component using this hook mounts, use an empty dependency array. Best practice is also to cancel the `fetch` (via [`AbortContoller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)) if the component unmounts before it finishes:

```
const useHttpRequest = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        const controller = new AbortController();
        fetch( "https://frontend-assignment-api.goodrequest.com/api/v1/shelters", {
            signal: controller.signal,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((shelters) => dispatch(fetchShelters(shelters.shelters)));
        return () => {
            // Unmounting, cancel the fetch if it's still happening
            controller.abort();
        };
    }, []);
  );
};
```

I also added handling for the `fetch` API footgun. `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors, so a 404, or 500 error would take you to your code doing the call to `json()`. But your server probably doesn't return JSON for 404 or 500 errors (though it could). So I added a check, more in my blog post [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).